# How to scroll to the bottom of a UITableView on the iPhone without seeing the scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios-autolayout, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a `UITableView` that is populated with cells of variable height. I would like the table to scroll to the bottom when the view is pushed into view.

I currently have the following function:

```
[self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

I'm using autolayout, dynamic table cells and `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as row height. I set `estimatedRowHeight = 100`

The above code works fine in `viewDidLoad` however this has the unfortunate side effect of displaying the top of the table when the view first appears and then jumping to the bottom. I would prefer it if the table view could be scrolled to the bottom before it appears.

Please note: I'm loading data from core data.

Any guidance would be much appreciated, even if it's just a case of telling me what I have is all that is possible.

Comment: Have you tried to call the scroll function in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` ?

Comment: Yes. But it the issue still there.  @MarwenDoukh-MaruänDuch

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, the order of the calls is correct: `viewDidLoad` should be called before the view is rendered, so the only thing that comes to my mind is that probably `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` is asynchronous. Maybe there's something you can do with `UIScrollViewDelegate` (remember, `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`) - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate?language=objc

Maybe you can do something like hiding the view on `onLoad` and showing it on `scrollViewDidScroll:`. I don't have time to test and paste a snippet but... maybe it helps :) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works !!!. But in low memory devices, I'm facing the issue again. I don't know why it is happening there only. It works fine in iPhone 8 and above, but issue is there in iPhone 6s.

Comment: Also in low performance devices, hiding/ showing views is not working properly as user can see the delay.

Comment: Hehe to be honest, I don't think iPhone 6s qualifies as "low memory", I expected an iPhone 3GS or so :) But if that's your case, make sure the change of visibility is the last line on the `scrollViewDidScroll:` callback. It's the only thing that comes to mind, because the race condition due to asynchronism should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty reliable...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;

    [self.tableView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:^(BOOL b) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:numRows - 1 inSection:numSections - 1];
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
    }];

}
```

Replace `numRows` and `numSections` with your data count(s).